# How to pass by parameter for pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pydev, pytest

I am trying to test the methods as specified in my class. I have been doing this by global to pass into my method like,

`csv.preprocess_col(df, field, remove_invalid_rows_or_raise_exception =0)`

with a global df to a path.

But for now I would like to pass by parameter through functions by doing `test_df(df)` instead of the regular `test_df()` to test my functions `(csv.preprocess_col)` inside it but I keep getting this fixture `df` not found error.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Just a curious question, for pytest is it ok to do by global to pass the parameters into the function?

Answer (score 1):

pytest supports test parametrization in [several well-integrated ways](https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html):

> - pytest.fixture() allows to define parametrization at the level of fixture functions.
> - @pytest.mark.parametrize allows to define parametrization at the function or class level, provides multiple argument/fixture sets for a particular test function or class.
> - pytest_generate_tests enables implementing your own custom dynamic parametrization scheme or extensions.

A few examples [here](https://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html).